# Is it possible to use default Magento colorPicker in 'Update Attributes' action?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, uicomponent, installdata, bulk-actions

I am trying to use default Color Picker component of Magento.

If I edit products individually the color picker works perfectly. Once I try the update attributes action from `Catalog->Products` page I get:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class colorPicker does not exist

Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class colorPicker does not exist
#1 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:49]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:100]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/Factory.php:81]
#5 Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/AbstractForm.php:155]
#6 Magento\Framework\Data\Form\AbstractForm->addField() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/Fieldset.php:214]
#7 Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset->addField() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Form/Element/ElementCreator.php:55]
#8 Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Element\ElementCreator->create() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Form.php:193]
#9 Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form->_setFieldset() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Action/Attribute/Tab/Attributes.php:90]
#10 Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Action\Attribute\Tab\Attributes->_prepareForm() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Form.php:156]
#11 Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form->_beforeToHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1096]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1101]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:671]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Tabs.php:492]
#15 Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tabs->getTabContent() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/widget/tabs.phtml:58]
#16 include() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:271]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:301]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php:129]
#20 Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1097]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1101]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:671]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:533]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#27 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#28 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#29 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#30 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#31 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#32 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#33 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#34 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#35 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#36 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#37 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#38 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#39 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#40 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#41 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#42 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#43 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#44 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#45 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#46 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#47 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:954]
#48 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:37]
#49 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php:258]
#50 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php:171]
#51 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult() called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:24]
#52 Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:141]
#53 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#54 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:40]
```

I have in my InstallData:

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute($entityTypeId, $attribute, [
    'type'                       => 'text',
    'input'                      => 'colorPicker',
    'label'                      => 'Colour',
    'default'                    => '#000',
    'user_defined'               => 1,
    'searchable'                 => 0,
    'visible'                    => true,
    'visible_on_front'           => 0,
    'visible_in_advanced_search' => 0,
    'group'                      => $customGroupName,
    'sort_order'                 => 20,
    'required'                   => false,
    'global'                     => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
    'filterable'                 => false,
    'comparable'                 => false,
    'used_in_product_listing'    => true,
    'unique'                     => false,
]);
```